# Get value of selected LI and remove it from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have a list of user inputted strings, and want to be able to delete one individual item, while also removing it from the array. I am able to remove it successfully from the DOM, but not from the array.

So far I have tried to get the value of the selected LI and select the indexof that specific LI

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.delete', function () {
    let deletedItem = $(this).closest('li')
    let itemValue = $(this).closest('li').val()
    let index = items.indexOf(itemValue);
    if(index != -1) {
        items.splice(index, 1);
    }
    deletedItem.remove();
});
```

This does not delete it from my array, any ideas how it would be done?

Comment: Did you check what is the value of the array right after the .splice() method?

Comment: Also possible mismatches between .val() and array elements; upper/lowercase differences, extra whitespace?

Comment: I solved it, since in my li I also have a button that got passed in to the itemValue, so the value was incorrect in the array

Comment: Great, in the future post a little more context to help us answer without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// To delete element from an array you had to keep track of the index in which the element exist. check the below example:

 // Create an array of strings;
    let array = ["Hello", "Boy", "Happy", "Fun"];

    // search for the index of item to be deleted in array
    let index = array.indexOf("Boy");
    console.log(index); // output: 1;

    // The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements
    array.splice(index, 1); // Return the removed item;

    // Check item present
    console.log(array); // output: [ 'Hello', 'Happy', 'Fun' ];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
let items = [1,2];

$(document).on('click', 'button.delete', function () {
    let deletedItem = $(this).closest('li')
    let itemValue = $(this).closest('li').val() 
    let index = items.indexOf(itemValue);
    
    if(index != -1) {
      items.splice( index ,1); // <-- Do this
    }
    deletedItem.remove();
    
    console.log(items);
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li value="1">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </li>

  <li value="2">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </li>
  
   <li value="3">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </li>
  <li value="4">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Forcing it into one line makes it less readable, offers less opportunity for error checking, and in this case has nothing to do with the OPs issue. Also, if a match is not found it will always remove the last item of the array with `items.splice(-1,1)`